# Lines and pixels in DTM

Tags: r, lidr

I'm creating DTM from lidar data using lidR.

I get vertical lines and a pixelated appearence in some areas. I've tried different algorithms (knnidw and tin).

```
library(lidR)

fil = '/home/bera/GIS/the_input.laz'

las <- readLAS(fil)
dtm <- grid_terrain(las, res=0.5, algorithm = knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))
crs(dtm) <- CRS('+init=EPSG:3006')

writeRaster(dtm, '/home/bera/GIS/the_output_DEM=05_knnidw.tif')
```

How can I get rid of them?

[image]

THe lines are there if you look closely at plot of the las density:

```
las2 <- readLAS(fil,  filter = "-inside 6760548 364038 6760505 363991")
d <- grid_density(las, 5)
plot(d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is made of narrow and tight strips of points with gaps in between. Moreover the strips are particularly dense because the point-cloud has probably been sampled with a two sensors acquisition system. The `UserData` attribute is populated with `0`s and `1`s which probably mean there was two sensors or something like that.

[image]

When computing a DTM with a resolution of 50 cm you get all the tiny details including the artifacts from the uneven sampling. The problem is emphasized by a particularly dense amount of ground points. You see the same in the density raster of course. Yet when I plot the shaded DTM in R it is not that bad.

```r
shade = function(dtm)
{
  ter <- raster::terrain(dtm, opt = c("slope", "aspect"))
  raster::hillShade(slope = ter$slope, aspect = ter$aspect)
}

las = readLAS("20D023_67600_3625_25.laz", filter = "-inside 362500 6760500 363000 6761000")
projection(las) <- 3006

dtm = grid_terrain(las, 0.5, knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))
plot(shade(dtm), col = gray(1:50/50))
```

I think a simple solution is to compute the DTM with a resolution of 1 m which is more common. You will miss some details but it seems that the way the point cloud as been sampled prevent to "zoom" to much. You could also compute only on points from one channel.

```r
ud0 = filter_poi(las, UserData == 0)
dtm2 = grid_terrain(ud0, 1, knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))
plot(shade(dtm2), col = gray(1:50/50))
```

Comment: How do you check the UserData attribute? I've tried `readLAS(fil, select = "u", filter = "")` and `las@UserData`? I know they have used two different sensors in the national scan, maybe this tile is one where they used both. Maybe I can use a if statement like, if userdata==something res=0.5 else res=1

Comment: Use `las$UserData` to access the attribute

Comment: (`unique(c(las$UserData)`)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets this problem it is possible to make a hillshade (which is why I'm creating the DTM/DEM) look alot better with Cubic Spline interpolation (I'm not up- or downsampling, the resolution is the same):

[image]